# Tunnel my ssh connection to a Linux server via a remote windows server(2003)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, putty, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to a linux server from my local windows machine. But the linux server can only be accessed via another windows server machine. So now I am doing:

Local windows machine--->remote desktop to windows server machine---->putty to linux machine.

Is there a way to make this connection directly from Putty on my local machine?

Also I have tried using putty to ssh into the remote windows server and use the ssh client on the remote windows server to connect to putty. But this will not give the colour options like putty and also I am not getting a full screen.

Comment: No, PuTTY is not capable of tunelling through RDP; although if the Windows Server machine runs an SSH **server**, it may be possible to tunnel through it (this is called "SSH multi-hop").

Comment: As I have mentioned, there is an ssh server running, but when I tunnel through it, I am not getting all the features of puTTy. There is no colour, no full screen, etc

Comment: *How* exactly do you "tunnel" through the Win server? This word can be used to mean multiple things. BTW, have you tried the multi-hop solution? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29778/ssh-tunnel-on-ssh-tunnel-between-windows-and-two-linux-machines

Comment: I logged into port 22 on Win server using putty and after logging in...I typed ssh user@linuxserver. This was using the native ssh client of the Win server and hence not getting features of putty. I am  trying multihop now.

Comment: See, that's why I asked - that's not tunneling at all. Try the option suggested in the *question* as well, that might be useful if there's no netcat on the Windows server.